# Is the completion of an arbitrary ring w.r.p. a maximal ideal a local ring?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Give an arbitrary commutative ring (not necessarily noetherian) $A$ with $\mathfrak{m}$ a maximal ideal. Is the completion $\hat{A}$ w.r.t. the ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ a local ring?　If so, is the maximal ideal of $\hat{A}$ generated by $\mathfrak{m}$, i.e., is it equal to $\mathfrak{m}\hat{A}$?

I know that this is true when $A$ is noetherian.

Comment: Yes. You can find those things in Bourbaki's Algèbre Commutative.

Answer (score 4):

Yes for the first question : see Bourbaki *Commutative Algebra* III, § 2, Proposition 19. No for the second question : see *loc. cit.*, exercise 12.